# Wordpress custom url without using any of the custom tags given

Tags: plugin-development, url-rewriting, import

I have a url like this:

`www.domainname.com/product/productname` which obviously uses a wordpress custom postlink using the custom tags given to me (%postname% as my products are just custom post types) however I would like it to be `www.domainname.com/[metaproperty1]/[metaproperty2][metaproperty3]`

where meta property 1 and 2 are taxonomies that relate to sale status and location of product and meta property 3 is an id (but crucially not the post id - it's an id generated by an API that an importer uses to add products to the DB)
so essentially I need to programatically set the new permalink. Any clues? I'm currently looking at using the `register_post_type` function to register my custom post type with the 'rewrite' option and including placeholders like %metaproperty1% etc etc. that would be swapped out later on with the

```
$wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag
```

function,
is this the correct way of thinking about it?

Comment: Yes, I'd also use [`add_rewrite_tag()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_tag/). But you may still need the `product` (the rewrite base) in the permalink, to avoid conflicts with Page (or any other existing) rewrite rules.

Comment: yes, and also I am using wp_get_post_terms to get the terms to replace the placeholders. seems like a good solution however I've realised that some products dont have one of the meta property's im trying to use :P different problem for a different thread though. if i can't solve it on my own!